# Why isn’t my autoreleased object getting released?

Tags: cocoa, macos, memory-management, autorelease

I am debugging a weird memory management error and I can’t figure it out. I noticed that some of my objects are staying in memory longer than expected. I checked all my memory management and finally got to the very improbable conclusion that some of my `autorelease` operations don’t result in a `release`. Under what circumstances is that possible? I created a small testing `Canary` class that logs a message in `dealloc` and have the following testing code in place:

```
NSLog(@"On the main thread: %i.", [NSThread isMainThread]);
[[[Canary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

According to the code we’re really on the main thread, but the `dealloc` in `Canary` does not get called until much later. The delay is not deterministic and can easily take seconds or more. How is that possible? The application runs on a Mac, the garbage collection is turned off (*Objective-C Garbage Collection* is set to *Unsupported* on the target.) I am mostly used to iOS, is memory management on OS X different in some important way?

Comment: Memory management under Mac OS X is different in that GC is available. When you don't opt into GC, then no, it's no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a blog post by Mike Ash called [More Fun With Autorelease](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/more-fun-with-autorelease.html) that explains the source of this problem. Quote:

> As everybody knows, every time you go
>   through the event loop, Cocoa blows
>   away the old pool and makes a new one
>   for you, so that all of your
>   autoreleased objects go away and your
>   new ones go into a fresh pool. That
>   way you never build up more objects
>   than get produced during a single
>   event loop cycle. The key word is “event loop”. In
>   Apple's infinite wisdom, things that
>   aren't real actual NSEvents don't
>   trigger the pool.
>
> I'm currently working on an app that
>   spends a lot of time in the background
>   doing dark, unspeakable things with
>   NSStreams on the main thread. I
>   encountered a bug where one of my
>   objects can get destroyed in the
>   middle of handling a stream event,
>   which left it open to getting other
>   stream events after it was
>   deallocated. (…)
>
> The obvious fix was to simply do
>   `[[self retain] autorelease]` before
>   making the problem call. And fix it it
>   did, except instead of my dealloc
>   happening in the middle of my event
>   handler, it never happened at all.
>
> Until I clicked on my app’s dock icon.
>
> At least the solution was easy. Post
>   an `NSApplicationDefined` event in the
>   stream event handler, and autoreleased
>   objects get destroyed on schedule.

I swear I have to read the blog from cover to cover, it’s a good time investment.

Comment: Yup, that's about it. We used to do something far hackier in Growl, but that's what we're doing now and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The only circumstance in which `autorelease` does not behave as expected is when there is no autorelease pool on the current thread. There are only a few situations where you can expect this to occur, and if it does, you get a very loud log message printed to the console. If you're not seeing that log, then `autorelease` is behaving appropriately. Far more likely is the fact that something on your code is calling `retain` on this Canary object and then never releasing it.

Comment: I’m sure I’m not retaining the testing object, I’m literally doing `[[[Canary alloc] init] autorelease]` without even using the return value. I found out that `autorelease` *does* get called some time later, but with a great delay. I think my problem has something to do with run loop behaviour, I’ll add more information tomorrow.

Comment: `autorelease` gets called immediately. Zero delay. What it does do is call `release` at a later date. Typically this occurs when control passes back to the run loop.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t express myself clearly. I meant that the `release` from the autorelease pool is delayed.

Answer (score 2):

Autoreleased objects do not get released until their pool is drained. So, if you are looping through images with an autoreleased buffer, it would be good to create and drain a pool every time through the loop.

Comment: If you're only creating a couple of objects in each pass through the loop, you don't want to create an autorelease pool every time. If you create 10 or more then it's fine. Also, if your loop isn't particularly long, then there's no real need for an autorelease pool. If you're running a heavy loop hundreds of times, or a light loop thousands of times, then you might want one.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are autoreleasing this into the application's pool, it won't get released (the pool won't get drained) until the application processes an event. This makes memory management in background applications tricky, as we found out in Growl. If you're autoreleasing the object into a pool you created in `main`, then running the application, then that pool will never get drained, because the application terminating will exit the process first.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, my application runs in background, that’s very likely the source of my problems. Can you submit that as an answer? I’d be grateful for further pointers, too.